# Show full log string in pm2 monit

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, pm2

I use sequelize.logger to log mysql query but in `pm2 monit` command I can't see the full of query.

this part not show `where clause` and I want this not `select ...` query.

Anyone have any idea for this ? or can I modify monit to show full log ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. If I correct understanding what you want. You just need to use `pm2 logs` this command shows you whatever in console log or other debuggers.

`pm2 monit` is for monitoring usages and other minor features.